# About the template efficiency

Tags: windows-phone-7

For some time already I am breaking my head on the following. Say we have a control with this default style:

```
<Style TargetType="r:PhoneButton">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
  <Setter Property="ActiveMargin" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="r:PhoneButton">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding ActiveMargin}">
                    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Above template is a bit simplified, but it is written in the same way as the standard Button template. (In fact we took the standard template and tweaked it a bit.)

However, I can't help, but see a couple of performance problems:

1. Padding is first initialized to 0, then changed to (10,3,10,5). What would we lose if we deleted the setter from the style and used the default property value (10,3,10,5)?
2. Same thing for BorderBrush. Instead of the style setter we could use default value 
   (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"]
3. Above brush could be made static and reused for Foreground default.
4. Etc. We could get rid of all style setters. The style would now contain only the template definition. However, even that could be moved into the code. (We can load the template from the string using the method XamlReader.Load().)
5. Using TemplateBinding is surely faster than standard Binding. However, if we have the template in the code, then for the DependencyProperties that are defined in our class (such as ActiveMargin) we have the option to fully remove the bindings: We can use PropertyChangedCallback instead.

If you think that we can get only peanuts using above techniques, then here is a concrete example:
I had a form containing 11 rather complex controls - each one was a composition of 2 or more simpler controls. After using above techniques:

- Initial form load was faster by 25%
- Subsequent **form loads were faster by 40%**.

What I measured was the time spent between entering the page constructor and the page Loaded event. Hence the measured time included also the page initialization. (The page contained standard header and application bar with custom icons). In other words the real performance gains were substantially higher than above mentioned 25/40%.

My question:
**What kind of problems do you see when using above optimizations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be removing flexibility (number of bindings and configurable properties) and the number of changes made for each templated item in order to improve performance.

The consequence of the changes realting to flexibility mean that in the future you won't have as much flexibility, should you need it. Depending on the application and your circumstances this may or may not be acceptable. - If you're building something for a single app then it shouldn't be a problem. (Don't worry about minor problems you may have in the future.) However, if you're developing a control you plan on reusing then it's flexibility may be important.

Comment: Can you please explain how the removal of the style setter for the Margin impacts the flexibility? 
In this concrete case the control being optimized is part of a control library. 
Ok, the main app cannot modify the default margin because it is not present in the default style - but who would do that?
On the other hand the user stil can style the control and define suitable margin there.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I didn't mean to imply that removing the styling impacted flexibility. It doesn't. But the extra work of [re]applying the style each time will have an impact.

Comment: As for the bindings: Lets take the ActiveMargin. In the first solution this DP is bound to the Border margin. 2nd solution uses PropertyChangedCallback handler which updates the same Border margin. What do I loose in the 2nd case? I think the user stil can re-template the control and attach a new meaning to the ActiveMargin. Ok, I see some risk, but in fact this ActiveMargin case isn't the best example for the binding removal, there are lots of cases that are much safer.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you took the effort, but... I don't see any lost bindings, any lost properties, any extra styling effort that would be added because of described changes. Perhaps the problem is my insufficient knowledge, hence I would be thankful if you could give me an advice what to read/study.